# Eclipse for .Net developer

Tags: .net, eclipse

In Eclipse, what is a "Package" explained in .NET terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package in java is most comparable to a namespace in .NET.

EDIT:

As pointed out by R0MANARMY, in Java the folder structure & where classes are dictate which package they belong to. In .NET classes can be marked as belonging to any namespace regardless of the folder they are in.

Comment: But without the miserably nested folder structure.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: If you're looking for them on the file system, yes.  It also make refactoring and moving classes between namespaces a pain in the ass.  Six of one, half a dozen of the other really.

Answer (score 0):

A Java package is something like a namespace in .NET